# EXT JS using list showing values using table. In the table header repeat to all rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

i m new in ext js now i m using one table in the listing

```
using table th and tr tags

 items: 
    [
        {
            xtype: 'list',
            itemTpl: '<div> <table > <tr><th> CountDown </th> 
                      <th> Date and Time</th> </tr> 
                      <tr> <td> {countValue}</td><td> {createdDateTime}
                      </td></tr></table> </div>'
        }
    ]
```

output is coming like that now Table headers should not repeat in the table
[image: output is coming like that now]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for `tpl` parameter instead of `itemTpl`.

> **itemTpl** - The tpl to use for each of the items displayed in this DataView.
>
> **tpl** - A String, Ext.Template, Ext.XTemplate or an Array of strings to form an Ext.XTemplate. Used in conjunction with the data and tplWriteMode configurations.

Example:

```
tpl: [
    '<div><table>',
        '<th> CountDown </th>',
        '<th> Date and Time</th>',
        '<tbody>', 
            '<tpl for=".">', 
                '<tr><td>{countValue}</td><td>{createdDateTime}</td></tr>',
            '</tpl>', 
        '</tbody>',
    '</table></div>'
]
```

> It look's like in `DataView.List` `tpl` can't be overrided. If you
>   must attach something custom - you need to create new widget on your own.

Maybe are you looking for xtype `grid` instead, check example on the fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2u6g

Comment: thank you so much but in the result it showing blank why?

Comment: If my answer is this what you need, select it - as an appropriate answer.